# Returing result of asynchronous function within Async.map

Tags: javascript, async.js

I'm very new to JS and functional programming in general and am struggling to find a graceful solution to this problem. Essentially, I want to make async requests to a MongoDB server, and return the results to an async to map function. The problem I am having in that the actual function within `async.map` is asynchronous itself. I would like to know a graceful solution here, or at least get a pointer in the right direction! Thanks!

```
  async.map(subQuery,
    function(item){
      collection.distinct("author", item, function(err, authors){
        counter++;
        console.log("Finished query: " + counter);

        var key = item['subreddit'];
        return { key: authors };
      })
    },

    function(err, result){
      if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else{
        console.log("Preparing to write to file...");

        fs.writeFile("michaAggregate.json", result, function() {
          console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
      }

      db.close();
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should process item only when the data is fetched. Just use callback That the common way of JavaScript. Like this:

```
var processItem = function(item){  
// Do some street magic with your data to process it

// Your callback function that will be called when item is processed.
onItemProccessed();
}

async.map(subQuery,
function(item){
  collection.distinct("author", item, function(err, authors){
    counter++;
    console.log("Finished query: " + counter);

    var key = item['subreddit'];
    processItem(item);
  })
},

function(err, result){
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else{
    // That string added **ADDED** 
    console.log('HEEY! I done with processing all data so now I can do what I want!');
    console.log("Preparing to write to file...");

    fs.writeFile("michaAggregate.json", result, function() {
      console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
  }

  db.close();
}
);
```

**ADDED**

By the specification of `async.map` you can see:

https://github.com/caolan/async

`async.map(arr, iterator, callback):`

`callback(err, results) - A callback which is called when all iterator functions have finished, or an error occurs. Results is an array of the transformed items from the arr.` As you see that callback is exactly what you need!

Comment: Ok. In this case, how would I do something once I have processed *all* the things?

Comment: At the end of `processItem()` just call the function you need

Comment: That will call n times though, correct? I just want to call it once.